# Getting Latex code (.tex) that produces R package vignette

Tags: r, package, latex, tex

I have an R package that produces a vignette when I build it. I would like to get the .tex file that produces the vignette. Right now, only a pdf is produced. Any ideas about how I can get the .tex file that produces that .tex file?

Answer (score 0):

1. [Go to CRAN on Github](https://github.com/cran)
2. Find the package
3. Go to its `vignettes` folder
4. ???
5. PROFIT

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, my package doesn't produce a vignette folder. Also, it appears that some packages still don't produce the .tex file.

Comment: You are being secretive about "your package", so it's hard to help you further.

Comment: This is what I needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832759/how-to-create-r-documentation-file-rd-in-latex/31632383#31632383

Comment: … but that's for R documentation, not vignettes?