# Get single latex file instead of PDF for documentation of R package

Tags: r, latex, documentation

I would like to get the Latex source for the PDF that is built when executing

```
R CMD Rd2pdf /path/to/mypackage
```

for building the R package documentation.
It would be very nice if I could get the documentation as a latex document such that I could easily include it in another latex document as an appendix and have a continuous page numbering.

I have only seen the possibility to compile the files one by one from `.Rd` to `.tex`:
[How to create R documentation file (.Rd) in latex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832759/how-to-create-r-documentation-file-rd-in-latex), which points to the function `tools::Rd2latex` and the question [How do I convert Rd files to pdf for a package that I am creating in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779864/how-do-i-convert-rd-files-to-pdf-for-a-package-that-i-am-creating-in-r) which points to the command

```
R CMD Rdconv -o x.tex --type=latex man/x.Rd
```

Both commands only work on single `.Rd` files. The created files lack the header/definitions. So I would have to sort and include each file manually in the final latex file. It would be nice if there is some way to get the latex document in a simpler way.

Comment: (you don't need the latex source to include the pdf with continuous page numbering, have a look at pdfpages package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
R CMD Rd2pdf path/to/package/man --no-clean
```

In addition to the PDF file, this creates a folder containing the auxiliary files, including the `tex` source file.

Comment: This worked very well. I just had to add the Rd.sty file to my folder, add `\usepackage[times,inconsolata]{Rd}` to my latex file and could paste the content between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` into the appendix.